# Change color in runtime as loop

Tags: c#, wpf

So i have 10 TextBlocks named:

```
x:Name="anlage1" ... x:Name="anlage10"
```

I want to change at Runtime the BG Color to Red in a loop

```
Brush red= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

for(int i=0; i < 11;i++)
{
anlage[i].Background = red;
}
```

unfortunately the syntax anlage[i] is not working, any solutions for that?

Also this is not working  `FindName(anlage+i).Background = red;`

Comment: WPF is able to bind properties. `<TextBlock x:Name="anlage1" Background="{Binding Background}">` . Also make sure you're using `System.Windows.Media.Brush` and not `System.Drawing.Brush`. They're not compatible and you'll get binding errors.

Comment: anlage10.Background = red; is working fine only the iteration with "i" is throwing me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping 11 times.

Should be 0 to 9 and hence <10 since it's zero indexed.

```
for(int i=0; i < 10;i++)
{
   anlage[i].Background = red;
}
```

Have you allowed for the first textblock being zero?

I tried this with just 3 textblocks.
You need to cast whatever is found to TextBlock ( or a control so it has a background for sure ).
And they need to have been rendered.

My markup is:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="0" Name="anlage0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="1" Name="anlage1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="2" Name="anlage2"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Code:

```
    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ((TextBlock)FindName("anlage" + i)).Background = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
```

Which works ok.

[image]